# System throwing error for simple codings

Tags: apex, class, static

```
Public class StaticExample
{
    Public static void method1()
    {
        System.debug(‘I am static method’);
    }
    Public  void method2()
    {
        System.debug(‘I am static method’);
    }
}
```

---------------Debugger Apex code------------

```
StaticExample.method1();
StaticExample  e=new StaticExample();
e.method2();
```

---------------error-------------------

> Line: 1, Column: 1
> Variable does not exist: StaticExample

Comment: Did you save the `StaticExample` class?

Comment: @DavidReed The problem was subtle. The syntax highlighting gives away the problem, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text editor made the wrong apostrophes, resulting in code that failed to compile.

```
// This will not compile
System.debug(‘I am static method’);
// This one is okay
System.debug('I am static method');
```

Make sure you're not using Microsoft Word or some other "smart" editor to write your code. If copy-pasting, make sure the apostrophes are not "smart quotes."

Comment: Tq..It's Working

Comment: @Mahi Glad I could help!

Comment: Microsoft word, the best Code editor :D